# Dynamic Search Options for 2 Tables

Tags: php, mysql

here's my problem, I have 2 Tables involved here: TINVOICES and TJOBS

```
TINVOICES - Job_no
TINVOICES - Year
TJOBS - Staff
TINVOICES - Month
TJOBS - Country
TINVOICES - Paid
TJOBS - Client_no
TINVOICES - 30 Days
```

I want the search options to be dynamic, like it should accept search job and year, alone. or only paid or only month... and so on. I have 2 tables involved.
Could you please give me a work around for my approach?

See my codes below.

Thank you so much!

Here's my search options:

[image: Search Options]

---

```
 if (isset($_POST['job_no'])) {
        $job_no = $_POST['job_no'];
        if ($_POST['job_no'] != "") { $job_no = " job_no=".$job_no." AND"; $search += 1;}
    }
    ..other ifs

if ($search != 0) {
    if (isset($_POST['country'])) {
        if ($_POST['country'] == "") {
            $query = "WHERE $job_no$month$id$year$staff_no$paid";
        }
        else {
            $query = "AND $job_no$month$id$year$staff_no$paid";
        }
    }
    else{
        $query = "WHERE $job_no$month$id$year$staff_no$paid";
    }
}                                       

//Remove string AND on the end of a query if found
if (substr($query, -3) == "AND") { $query = substr($query, 0, -3); } 

if (isset($_POST['country']) && $_POST['country'] != "") {      
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    if ($country == "All") {
        $sql = "SELECT p . * FROM tinvoices $query AS p ";
    }
    else if ($country == "Middle East") {
        $sql = "
        SELECT p . *
        FROM tinvoices AS p 
        LEFT JOIN tjobs AS j 
        ON p.job_no = j.job_no 
        WHERE j.location =  'Qatar' OR j.location = 'UAE' $query ";
    }
    else {
        $sql = "
        SELECT p . *
        FROM tinvoices AS p
        LEFT JOIN tjobs AS j
        ON p.job_no = j.job_no
        WHERE j.location =  '$country' $query ";
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());
}
elseif (isset($_POST['client_no']) && $_POST['client_no'] != "") {      
    $client_no = $_POST['client_no'];
    $sql = "
        SELECT p . *
        FROM tinvoices AS p
        LEFT JOIN tjobs AS j
        ON p.job_no = j.job_no
        WHERE j.location =  '$country' $query ";
    echo $sql;
}
else {
    $sql = "SELECT p . * FROM tinvoices AS p $query";
    //echo $sql;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Dynamic in what way? it would be great if you formulate your question in a way we can understand what you are trying to do, what you tried to do, and what doesn't work

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. I want the search options to be dynamic, like it should accept search job and year, alone. or only paid or only month... and so on. I have 2 tables involved.

Comment: You are already on the right track, just split the "WHERE" part, and keep the first part of your queries as one, so that $sql = "select ..", is then added $sql .= "where .."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TO make searching dynamic, first of all make sure the form element name is exactly the same as in the database table field. For two tables, you can prefix the form element name with tablename and then field. For example

> if your database field name is location in tinvoices table then your location element name should be tinvoices_location

So when the form is submitted you can loop through posted data like this
Assume you have two table table1 and table2

```
    $sql = "SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.table2_column WHERE ";

$conditions = array();
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $tableFields = explode('_', $key);
    $conditions[] = $tableFields[0].'.'.$tableFields[1].' = "'.$value.'"';   // will produce table1.location = "Qatar"
    }
$sql .= implode(' AND ', $conditions);  // will produce condtion1 AND condition2 and so on

$sql .= ' ORDER BY table1.column';
```

in loop you can also target specifi elements using

```
if(preg_match('/table1_/', $key)){
//populate conditions array
}
```

Next you can modify it as you want.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that. I'll try this one out now and I'll get back to you. And yes, I have the same form name and database field name Thanks.

Comment: Got it working! Just tweak some little things around. Thanks bro!